# Rails/Ruby Error When Creating Database: Unable to load the EventMachine C extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, eventmachine

**Update:**

the eventmachine gem is installed and in my gemfile:

```
 eventmachine (1.0.0, 0.12.10)
```

**Please help! Trying to create a database with the following:**

```
Fitzs-MacBook-Pro:twilio_insanity Fitz$ rake db:create'
```

**Returns the following error:**

> Unable to load the EventMachine C extension; To use the pure-ruby
>   reactor, require 'em/pure_ruby' rake aborted! cannot load such file --
>   rubyeventmachine
>   /Users/Fitz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/eventmachine.rb:8:in
>   `require'
>   /Users/Fitz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/eventmachine.rb:8:in`
>   '
>   /Users/Fitz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin.rb:7:in
>   `require'
>   /Users/Fitz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin.rb:7:in`
>   '
>   /Users/Fitz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in
>   `require'
>   /Users/Fitz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in`
>   block (2 levels) in require'
>   /Users/Fitz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in
>   `each'
>   /Users/Fitz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in`
>   block in require'
>   /Users/Fitz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in
>   `each'
>   /Users/Fitz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in`
>   require'
>   /Users/Fitz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler.rb:128:in
>   `require'
>   /Users/Fitz/Desktop/twilio_insanity/config/application.rb:7:in`' /Users/Fitz/Desktop/twilio_insanity/Rakefile:5:in
>   `require' /Users/Fitz/Desktop/twilio_insanity/Rakefile:5:in`'
>   /Users/Fitz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in
>   `eval'
>   /Users/Fitz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in`
>   ' (See full trace by running task with --trace)

```

Comment: Have you installed required gems? Run `gem list` in your project folder to see if you have required gems in place. try installing gems `gem install eventmachine`

Comment: yeah it is...updated my question to reflect that. any other thoughts?

Comment: [This comment in another thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9389570/1518852) seems promising for your issue.  Can you ensure that you have "gem eventmachine" or similar in your Gemfile, and can successfully bundle?

Comment: that was basically it...separate versions of ruby which was confusing my installed gems. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone kind of answered in comments...see below.

Basically though I had seperate versions of Ruby, which was getting confusing because some gems were only installed on certain versions of ruby.

**Fix was totally uninstalling ruby and rails, then reinstalling. Fixed it!**

This helped:

[This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332810/ruby-on-rails-cannot-load-such-file-eventmachine/9389570#9389570) in another thread seems promising for your issue. Can you ensure that you have "gem eventmachine" or similar in your Gemfile, and can successfully bundle? – Scott Helm Jan 6 at 6:24

Comment: while reinstalling seem like a crazy idea, in my case I had one version of ruby installed with `rvm` and another with `brew`. So this actually works

Comment: I fixed the issue by simply uninstalling eventmachine, and then installing it again.

Answer (score 11):

try to re-install the gem 'eventmachine'

```
$ gem uninstall eventmachine
```

then

```
$ bundle install  ( in the same folder with your Gemfile)
```

or just

```
$ gem install eventmachine ( if you are not using the Gemfile)
```

see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15140634/445908

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error on Windows after upgrading ruby from 1.9.3 to 2.4.
I tried every fix I found but the only thing that helped in the end was (not that obvious and therefore hard to find) to **reinstall** the new **Ruby** again **with 32 bit instead of 64**.

Also I installed Eventmachine with

```
gem install eventmachine --platform=ruby
```

to force native compilation, since I always get problems with msgpack, that can be solved like this (haven't tried it with the default `x86-mingw32`)

Answer (score 1):

I am on windows 10. `C:\Ruby25-x64\lib\ruby\gems>bundle install` showed `Could not locate Gemfile` error(though, i am having bundle gem installed and present at \gems location). Following worked for me to resolve Unable to load the EventMachine C extension error:

1. `gem uninstall eventmachine`
2. `gem install eventmachine --platform ruby`

Answer (score 0):

Just try the following:

```
apt-get install libssl0.9.8
```

It fixed the error on Ubuntu 12.4

Answer (score 0):

If any of this solutions don't work, try reinstalling eventmachine gem from sources using method that worked for me on OS X: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20950026/83055

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you bundle eventmachine in your Gemfile

```
gem "eventmachine"
```

Then `bundle install`.  [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9389570/1518852) seemed relevant to you.