# Eventmachine - Unable to load the Event Machine C Extension

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm trying to run the current development version of `Instiki` on windows 8.1. I use ruby 2.4 .  Bundle install succeeded. I also used the newest `Nokogiri 1.8.0` version that was released some days ago and this fixed a compatibility issue with Ruby 2.4 on windows systems.

When I run `instiki` , It says that the system is unable to load the Event Machine C Extension.

In more detail the Error message is :

```
Unable to load Event Machine C extension: To use the pure ruby reactor use 'require'em/pure_ruby
C:\instiki\vendor\rails\activesupport\lib\active_support\dependencies.rb:184: in 'require' cannot load such a file -- rubyeventmachine (missing source file)
```

If I understand this correctly , A file is missing which was required in some module so I might be able to circumvent this by including some other module ( "pure_ruby" rb file) that provides the same functionality  . Is this right ? I tried to re-install this gem with no effect. If this is so , how can I do this ?

Note : This is the first time I use ruby and I have limited experience in programming

Some progress : I required pure_ruby in the dependencies file , the half page  error report turned to two pages of errors which I can't decipher so this might be relevant.

Comment: See  this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134033/rails-ruby-error-when-creating-database-unable-to-load-the-eventmachine-c-exten and

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look at [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).